# Fetching a value displayed in a table based on 3 criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm struggling to figure out a formula to fetch a value in one sheet based on 3 criteria in another. This is my issue: 
[image]

Basically, I need a value in the cell "action extrapolation" based on a the cell "extrapolation type" (e.g. "surface") and the "ID cabinet". All the information is displayed in another sheet (Sheet2), like this:
[image]

I've tried the INDEX formula but it is leading me nowhere. I'm unsure of how to tell the formula to go find the info in the table.

Comment: you will need to use INDEX and MATCH for this, google how to use the 2 together, I will post an answer when I have time

Comment: ive posted an answer, needed a quick distraction form work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use INDEX & MATCH combined,

See the image below, I used the formula in cell L2:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$7,MATCH(J2,$A$1:$A$7,0),MATCH(K2,$A$1:$D$1,0))
```

Note where the $ are placed, these parts will be found in your second sheet.
(still keep them in though)

You will need to change this to suit your placement of tables etc.

[image]

Comment: many thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. So helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a table that looks similar to yours:

[image]

So, you need a value in the cell "action extrapolation" based on a the cell "extrapolation type" and the "ID cabinet". Following this method will fetch you a value from the columns "id cabinet" and "extrapolation type" and place them into a cell "Action Extrapolation".

In the first cell of the column (here D2) "Action Extrapolation", type in this formula and hit enter:

`=CONCATENATE(A2,"-", D2)`

where `A2` and `D2` corresponds to respective cells in `id cabinet` and `extrapolation type`.

Now, drag from the edge of that cell all way down, and you will have both of the corresponding values in the cell separated by a `-`. For example: `2-surface`. See this:

[image]

I hope this helps :)

Comment: thank you so much for your input. However, even if this is useful for me, I was more thinking of needing the value which corresponds to "2" and "Surface" together, so 0,57 in the screenshots I've attached :)

Comment: can you please elaborate on this? What do you need - 2,Surface (in text) or 0,57(in number)?

Comment: @ both, thanks for all this. I need 0,57 in number in my cell "action extrapolation". 0,57 being the value of the cabinet n°2 for the "surface" type. I hope I'm clear. And @PeterH, "he" is the right one!

Comment: My bad, I didn't quite get that :(